# unable to insert date and hostname at the end of each line in korn script

Tags: unix, ksh

I need to insert date and hostname to the end of the line in using ksh. The lines are output from the vmstat os that if a line  starts with a number I need to add Date and Hostname to the end of the line:

I have this test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

  while read line
  do
    printf "$line"
    if [[ "$line" =~ "^([0-9])" ]]; then
       date '+ %m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S'
       hostname
    else
       echo
    fi
  done
```

when I do this

```
vmstat 3 | test



syntax error at line 6 : `=~' unexpected
```

Comment: Don't use the name `test` as the name for your scripts, as most unix/linux systems already have more than one command by that name (either as `{/usr}/bin/test` or as a shell builtin, which may make it hard for others to reproduce your results.  Use `test.sh` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to use an implementation of `ksh` which does not know the `=~` operator, e.g. `ksh88`.

You can resort to e.g. `grep` to do the matching, for example

`test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/ksh

while read line; do
    printf "$line"
    if echo "${line}" | grep -q "^[0-9]"; then
        printf "%s %s" "$(
            date '+ %m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S'
        )" "$(hostname)"
    fi
    echo
done
```

Example run:

```
$ printf "foo\n3 bar\nquux\n" | ./test.sh
foo
3 bar 05-06-2013 18:53:59 myhostname
quux
```